# A:Hover not working on UL and LI

Tags: css, html

Good evening! I am currently in the process of creating a personal, mediocre, website to learn the fundamentals of CSS, HTML5, Javascript and PHP. I have got a navigation banner, a simple banner with opacity at the top of my website, this then has navigation links at the top right using an unordered list and then navigated via the CSS Document.

Here is my code to the list:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Home</li>
        <li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Downloads</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I have the divider inside of the navigation divider tag, I don't personally see an issue with this, also my CSS code is listed below:

```
a:hover 
{
    color: black;
    border: 1px #EEE;
}
```

I have used an alternative code which specifies the direct location including the divider ID for not only the un-ordered list but also main divider yet nothing works. Please let me know if you can help me and if you require any images or further code please inform me. Thanks, Knight.

Comment: An inline style overrides a CSS style. Don't use inline styles, they're "bad form" and lead to exactly this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong in your question.

The inline style has greater specificity and overrides the CSS `a:hover` styles. Put both the styles in a `<style>` block or separate stylesheet.

```
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
a:hover {
    color: black;
    border: 1px #EEE;
}
```

The [order of these is important](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/link-specificity.html).

Your anchor `<a href...>` tags are not closed.

```
<li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Home</li>
<!-- should be -->
<li><a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: white;">Home</a></li>
<!-- removing the style ... -->
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```

Your `border:` doesn't specify a border-style. It should, if for nothing else, safety against an unintended cascade.

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid #EEE;
}
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stephen61/pnwt93p8/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this inline-style `color: white;` will take precedence over your `a:hover { color: black; }` style. You can do a search on CSS specificity to learn more about this.

I would try removing inline styles (the `style` attribute). In general, you should try to never use them.

Try this instead:

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
    border: 1px #EEE;
}
```

Comment: I used an inline style as my text-decoration code was not working in CSS for the links. They still do not.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Just remove your inline styles. Take a look here:

**html**

```
<div id="list">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" />Home</li>
        <li><a href="#" />Downloads</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**css**

```
a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration : underline;
}
a {
    text-decoration : none;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3jk4cnjq/4/)